# displaying random images and click images

Tags: java, android, arrays

i want to display random images, and click some image, and show which images wrong or right

```
private int[] imgId = new int[] { R.drawable.info_mna,
        R.drawable.info_mn, R.drawable.panda_mna, R.drawable.panda_mn,
        R.drawable.share_mn, R.drawable.share_mna, R.drawable.riset_mn,
        R.drawable.game_mn };
```

for clicklistener

```
iv3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //not working
            if (imgId.length == imgId[1]) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "right",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: check my [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32007094/2553431)

Answer (score 1):

To get random image from array do this:

```
int id = imgId[new Random().nextInt(imgId.length)];
```

Then in `onClick()`

```
iv3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //not working 
        if (imgId.length == id) { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "right", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
    } 
});
```